# How to close a multiprocessing queue from a parent (consumer) process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Where using a multiprocessing queue to communicate between processes, many articles recommend sending a terminate message to the queue.
However, if a child process is the producer, if may fail expectedly, leaving the consumer without and notification to expect more messages.

However, the parent process *can* be notified if a process when a child dies.
It seems it should be possible for it to notify a worker thread in this process to quit and not expect more messages. But how?

```
    multiprocessing.Queue.close()
```

...doesn't notify consumers (Really? Wait? what!)

```
    def onProcessQuit(): # Notify worker that we are done.
        messageQ.put("TERMINATE")
```

... doesn't let me wait for pending work to complete.

```
    def onProcessQuit(): # Notify worker that we are done.
        messageQ.put("TERMINATE")
        # messageQ.close()
        messageQ.join_thread()  # Wait for worker to complete
```

... fails because the queue is not yet closed.

```
    def onProcessQuit(): # Notify worker that we are done.
        messageQ.put("TERMINATE")
        messageQ.close()
        messageQ.join_thread()  # Wait for worker to complete
```

... seems like it should work, but fails in the worker with a TypeError exception:

```
    msg = messageQ.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 94, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _recv_bytes
    return self._recv(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

```
            while !quit:
                try:
                   msg = messageQ.get(block=True, timeout=0.5)
                except Empty:
                   continue
```

... is terrible in that it unnecessarily demands trading shutdown latency without throttling the CPU.

Full example

```
import multiprocessing
import threading


def producer(messageQ):
    messageQ.put("1")
    messageQ.put("2")
    messageQ.put("3")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    messageQ = multiprocessing.Queue()
    def worker():
        try:
            while True:
                msg = messageQ.get()
                print(msg)
                if msg=="TERMINATE": return
                # messageQ.task_done()
        finally:
            print("Worker quit")
            # messageQ.close()  # End thread
            # messageQ.join_thread()

    thr = threading.Thread(target=worker, 
                           daemon=False)   # The work queue is precious.
    thr.start()

    def onProcessQuit(): # Notify worker that we are done.
        messageQ.put("TERMINATE") # Notify worker we are done
        messageQ.close()        # No more messages
        messageQ.join_thread()  # Wait for worker to complete

    def runProcess():
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer, args=(messageQ,))
        proc.start()
        proc.join()
        print("runProcess quitting ...")
        onProcessQuit()
        print("runProcess quitting .. OK")

    runProcess()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about the `producer` process not completing normally, then I am not sure what your question is because your code as is should work except for a few corrections: (1) it is missing an `import` statement, (2) there is no call to `runProcess` and (3) your worker thread is incorrectly a *daemon* thread (as such it may end up terminating before it has had a chance to process all the messages on the queue).

I would also use as a personal preference (and not a correction) `None` as the special *sentinel* message instead of `TERMINATE` and remove some extraneous queue calls that you don't really need (I don't see your explicitly closing the queue accomplishing anything that is necessary).

These are the changes:

```py
def producer(messageQ):
    messageQ.put("1")
    messageQ.put("2")
    messageQ.put("3")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing
    import threading

    SENTINEL = None

    def worker():
        try:
            while True:
                msg = messageQ.get()
                if msg is SENTINEL:
                    return # No need to print the sentinel
                print(msg)
        finally:
            print("Worker quit")


    def onProcessQuit(): # Notify worker that we are done.
        messageQ.put(SENTINEL) # Notify worker we are done

    def runProcess():
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer, args=(messageQ,))
        proc.start()
        proc.join()
        print("runProcess quitting ...")
        onProcessQuit()
        print("runProcess quitting .. OK")
        thr.join()

    messageQ = multiprocessing.Queue()
    thr = threading.Thread(target=worker)   # The work queue is precious.
    thr.start()
    runProcess()
```

Prints:

```None
1
2
3
runProcess quitting ...
runProcess quitting .. OK
Worker quit
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll update the question.
Your changes do work, although is hang if:  `SENTINEL = {}`
Any idea why?

Comment: You can't use `is` when comparing for the SENTINEL and must use the == operator. This is because the item `{}` that is read from the queue is only a copy of SENTINEL because of serialization/deserialization using `pickle`.

Comment: Doh -- Makes sense.

Comment: So the principle fix was removing `messageQ.close() ; messageQ.join_thread()` and adding thr.join().
I'm a little confused why these aren't allowed on the consumer end.
The docs don't seem to warn against it:   :-/ 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.close

Comment: I don't think those calls did any harm. They just say that there will be no more messages put on the queue and therefore the invisible thread you don't see that actually does all the putting of messages on the queue and exists so that the thread that actually issues the `put` call won't block can now terminate. This thread exists because a queue is built on top of a `multiprocessing.Pipe`, which has a very finite capacity and access to it must be serialized if multiple threads are doing `put` calls.

Comment: One problem you had was your `worker` thread was a daemon and will terminate as soon as the main process terminates, which occurs as soon as the `producer` process terminates. But the `worker`  thread has not necessarily retrieved all the messages.

Comment: Yes. I saw your fixed that (thanks). 
However, it's still not obvious why the consumer can't call q.close() and q.join.  The docs says all that close indicates is that the q is closed to new messages (in the consumer: the sentinel is sent, q.close called, but the the consumer raises an unexpected TypeError in this case - seems like a bug).

Comment: I added back the calls to `close` and `join_queue` and the program runs to completion without generating an exception. See updated code.

Comment: You can't have these calls in function `process` because `close` would  prevent `onProcessQuit` from putting the sentinel on the queue.

Comment: I ran the full text of your revision in Python 3.7 and 3.10. Both generated a TypeError exception in multiprocessing/connection.py.
Mysterious.

Comment: It ran okay under Python 3.8.5 (Windows) and Python 3.9.7 (Linux). You may have very well found a bug.

Comment: My bad! I had added the calls to `close` and `join_queue` inadvertently to an experimental copy of the code but ran the original program, which did not have those statements, and that is why I got no error. I now get an exception with those statements added. BUT: The error I get is a BrokenPipeError. This occurs in the `worker` thread, which is blocking on the call to `messageQ.get`. Perhaps the documentation is incomplete and the issue is that `close` should only be called when no more `get` calls are being done or will be done. ???